# SSRS Calculated Column in Buckets

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am working on a query and I did a `DateDiff` in my `Select` statement to create three columns creating minute differences between two columns in my query.  What I need to do now is put the data from those `DateDiff` results into buckets, but I am stuck on how to get this done.

These are the calculations from my `Select` statement:

```
,DATEDIFF (minute, ORD_MSG_MST.ORD_RCV_DTTM, PF_MST.ISSU_DTTM) AS 'Order_Issue'
,DATEDIFF (minute, ORD_MSG_MST.ORD_RCV_DTTM, UNIT_HIST.OCCR_DTTM AS 'Order_XM'  
,DATEDIFF (minute, UNIT_HIST.OCCR_DTTM, PF_MST.ISSU_DTTM) AS 'XM_IS'
```

I was going to try add this as a subquery in my `FROM` statement:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SELECT 
        count(CASE WHEN 'Order_XM'>= 0 AND 'Order_XM' < 10 THEN 1 END) AS '0 - 10',
        count(CASE WHEN 'Order_XM'>= 11 AND 'Order_XM' < 20 THEN 1 END) AS '11 - 20',
        count(CASE WHEN 'Order_XM'>= 21 AND 'Order_XM' < 30 THEN 1 END) AS '21 - 30',
        count(CASE WHEN 'Order_XM'>= 31 AND 'Order_XM' < 40 THEN 1 END) AS '31 - 40',
FROM ____) )
```

But I don't know what table I need to put in to my FROM statement.  And I'm not sure if this is really the correct way to do this.

Any thoughts on how you would get a calculated column in a query into buckets within the same query so I can create a Histogram in Report Builder?

I've done a lot of searching on this and haven't found anything where these are values that have been calculated. 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can take your initial query with the calculated `DateDiff` columns and use that as a subquery -- this will allow you then to have a primary query that does the bucketing.

You did not post most of your SQL, making it difficult to show an example that is perfectly relevant.  So instead I'll use the Northwind sample database from MS to show an example that should be easy enough to follow and fix your own query.

Northwind has an `Orders` table with two `DATETIME` columns: *RequiredDate* and *ShippedDate*.  My subquery calculates a `DateDiff` (with `days` rather than `minutes`) between these two columns and calls it `Diff`.  The primary query then calculates a `COUNT` for each of three buckets covering ranges of values.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Diff >= -50 AND Diff < -25 THEN 1 END) AS '-50 through -25',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Diff >= -25 AND Diff < 0 THEN 1 END) AS '-25 thorugh 0',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Diff >= 1 AND Diff < 25 THEN 1 END) AS '0 thorugh 25'
FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(day, RequiredDate, ShippedDate) AS 'Diff'
        FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
    ) a
```

Using this example I think you should be able to make similar changes to your own query to get the result you are looking for.